# Convex Optimization: Advantages of Symmetric Primal-Dual Algorithms?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

This is a follow-up to an answer on a previous question on PD algorithms: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1193928/36257

I have done some research learning the mechanics of how Infeasible PD algorithms work. In particular, Prof. Vandenberghe's lectures here were useful:

http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/ (lectures 14 through 18)
http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/pd.pdf (explains a typical symmetric Infeasible start PD algorithm)

It looks for my research application, I will be well-suited by using ECOS:

https://github.com/embotech/ecos
Background:
https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/ecos_ecc.pdf
http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/publications/coneprog.pdf

My question is this: my foray into conic programming began with Mr. Grant's suggestion to look into symmetric PD algorithms, but what are the full list of advantages (over a regular Barrier solver)?

For example, the following is important to me (from the answer):

```
most state-of-the-art algorithms today employ what is called a symmetric primal dual
method. There are very good reasons to do this, including the ability to start 
from an infeasible point, and even the ability to handle problems that are not   
strictly feasible in the first place
```

But why do symmetric conic algorithms in particular lead to this? Is it that only they, and not the barrier methods, have properties making this possible (e.g. self-scaling point that preserves the convex cone)? I feel like I learned the mechanics of how they work fairly decently, but I'm missing the bigger picture, the "why" of these algorithms.

To summarize, I want to follow up on the suggestion to use this class of conic PD algorithms for my work, but I need to be able to justify it a little more rigorously. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm guilty of oversimplification in the quoted paragraph. Is it possible to build a barrier method that can start at an infeasible point? Yes. See, for instance, section 10.3 of Boyd & Vandenberghe (though note: no convergence proof is offered). Should you? If you have no better choice. The *performance* of true symmetric/self-scaled primal-dual methods is significantly better. As to why, I think that's the subject of a literature search, and I'm not sure Math.SE is going to offer that for you.

Comment: I'll give you two resources: "Symmetric primal-dual math following algorithms for semidefinite programming" by J. Sturm & S. Zhang, and "Towards nonsymmetric conic optimization" by Yu. Nesterov.