# Undefined infeasible point in a convex programming package like CVXOPT

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, cvxpy

I am using CVXOPT, particularly to solve a nonlinear convex optimization problem. Either the objective function or the constraints involve some functions that are only defined in a strict subset of $\mathbf R^n$. For example, the function is the logarithm $\ln$. [It seems](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1193928/64809) that the package may well use *symmetric primal dual method* which allows infeasible points during the iteration. However, that would generate domain error from the functions. Does extending function to the whole of the Euclidean space help? For the example of the logarithm, I extend it so that $\ln(x)=-\infty$ or $-M$, and $\frac1x=\infty$ or $M$ $\forall x\le0$ for some very large positive $M$. Is this the practice to get around the problem? What are the more efficient ways to handle the problem?

---

Here is a specific example. Actually, this is modified from the [Example: equality constrained analytic centering of CVXOPT User's Guide](https://cvxopt.org/userguide/solvers.html#problems-with-nonlinear-objectives) to make the point of the issue of domain of definition.

```
import numpy as np
from cvxopt import matrix, log, mul, div, spdiag, solvers


np.random.seed(1)
A = matrix(np.random.randn(2,4))
b = matrix(np.random.randn(2))
m,n = A.size

def F(x=None,z=None):
  if x is None: return 0,matrix(1.0,(n,1))
  #if max(x) >= 0.0: return None
  f = -sum(log(-x))
  Df = ((-x)**-1).T
  if z is None: return f,Df
  H = spdiag(z[0]*(x**-2))
  return f,Df,H

G = spdiag([1.]*n)
h = matrix(0.0,(n,1))

f, Df, H = F(matrix(-1.0,(n,1)), matrix([-2.0]))

sol = solvers.cp(F,G=G,h=h,A=A,b=b)['x']
```

Comment: It is being automatically handled by the solver, as far as I know, as long as your problem is convex. And yes, it is a practice to extend functions as you describe (see Boyd's book).

Comment: @bodil: Are you sure it is handled by the solver with an explicit extension? Would you mind taking a look at the example I just added?

Comment: Is there a particular reason not to use the CVX modeling language to formulate your problem?

Comment: @bodil: Does the CVX modeling language handle this case? I am using Python and having trouble downloading CVXPY.

Comment: Yes! As long as your problem is convex, i.e. in the form $\min_x f(x) s.t. g_i(x)\leq 0, Ax = b$, where $f,g_i$ are convex. Or, as in your case $\max_x f(x)$, and $f$ is concave. You just need to specify your problem. I don't know how to do this with Python specifically, but with MATLAB is straightforward. Then, CVX chooses the appropriate solver, and the solver parameters for you automatically.

Comment: @V.S.e.H.: My $f$ is convex. It is $-\ln(-x), \forall x<0$. CVXOPT chooses particular solving algorithm automatically, but it seems to have run into trouble with $x$ running outside of the domain of definition of 
$\ln$ and becoming positive. Can you try my example in CVX and see if it ever runs into the infeasible and undefined region ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119872/discussion-between-v-s-e-h-and-hans).

Comment: @V.S.e.H.: For your information, the comment under my question https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/36915/36201 points out that this is a exponential convex conic programming which has a special algorithm.